# Detect if the reset password link sent by firebase as been used or expired

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

Is there is a way to know the if the reset password link (action link) sent by firebase as been used or expired when the user uses the link to go to the custom reset password page.

```
   this.afAuth
  .confirmPasswordReset(oobCode, new_password)
  .then(() => this.router.navigate(['reset-success']))
  .catch((err) => {
   this.router.navigate(['error']);
  });
```

According the way I did the user will be redirected to the reset password page.
I used the above call when the user submits the new password. Here if the firebase reset password link (action link) is used once or it is expired the user will be redirected to the error notification page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.code = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['oobCode'];
    this.apiKey=this.route.snapshot.queryParams['apiKey'];

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
    }
    const requestHeaders={
      headers : new HttpHeaders(headers)
    };

    let requestOobCode = {
      oobCode: this.code
    }
    let data = JSON.stringify(requestOobCode);
    this.http.post<any>('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:resetPassword?key=' + this.apiKey + '', data, requestHeaders).subscribe(data => {
      
      this.linkNotExpired = true;
    }, error => {
      this.router.navigate(['error-reset']);

    })
```

Firebase REST API provides a method to validate the action URL . Here we have to send  apiKey and oobCode of the action URL to the endpoint. If the  oobCode valid and not expired  will send a success response else will send error.
Refer the Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-verify-password-reset-code